# Filtering data set on first where clause then filtering left over data set on 2nd where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a table with order item and Order date.

I want to pull out all records which have order date in year 2020,But if the item does not have any order in 2020 then I want to pull out all records for that order

So If a item has a order in 2020 then only 2020 records
if it dose not have a order in 2020 then all other records

```
OrderItem   Order Date
----------------------
A           4/21/2020
A           7/22/2020
A           5/15/2019
B           2/20/2019
```

Expected Output

```
OrderItem   Order Date
----------------------
A           4/21/2020
A           7/22/2020
B           2/20/2019
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far so we can see how to work it into your existing query. I assume you also have an `Item` table, please show that also

Comment: @Charlieface I have quite a complex queries which finally return me these 2 columns in CTE or Temp table. I might not be able to share those due to security reasons. However you can consider these are only 2 columns which are needed to be worked upon. I have added expected output if that helps give clearity

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where (o.orderdate >= '2020-01-01' and o.orderdate < '2021-01-01') or
      not exists (select 1
                  from orders o2
                  where o2.orderitem = o.orderitem and
                        o2.orderdate >= '2020-01-01' and
                        o2.orderdate < '2021-01-01'
                 );
```

If "orders" is really a complicated query, you might find window functions are a better choice:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             count(case when o.orderdate >= '2020-01-01' and o.orderdate < '2021-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by orderitem) as cnt_2020
      from orders o
     ) o
where cnt_2020 = 0 or
      o.orderdate >= '2020-01-01' and o.orderdate < '2021-01-01';
```

This only references the "complex query" once.